# FullCalendar 2.1.1 addEventSource by function

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I was using fullcalendar 1.6 version. I upgraded to 2.1.1. But after upgrade addEventSource did not work .

```
function setCalendarEvents(start, end, callback){

        start = Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000);
        end = Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000);


        ajax({
            url : '<?php echo admin_url('event/events') ?>',
            data : {
                filter : {
                    filters : _filters
                },
                start : start,
                end:end
            },
            type : 'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            success : function(json){
                var events = [];
                callback(json);
            }
        });
    }
calendarObj.fullCalendar('addEventSource', setCalendarEvents);
```

It throws start.getTime() is not a function. I wrote to console, callback is false, start and end does not have getTime() method. I looked documentation http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/ but there is no enough information.

Comment: I think you are missing `$` with `$.ajax(`

Comment: No. ajax is function which is created by me and the error is "TypeError: start.getTime is not a function"

Comment: start and end are momentjs objects. You get unix timestamp like this: start.unix()

Comment: @RichardHermanson can you add answer. i will check your answer as correct answer

Comment: That's ok, was such a minor issue

Answer (score 1):

i did this chage and it worked.

> From start.getTime() >> start.toDate().getTime()

Comment: you can find more information here http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/